# Issue to make click on <a> tag in functional test with selenium

Tags: python, django, selenium

I am to make a functional test and I need to make click on `<a>` tag, but I try some ways and really I don't know, I try with the commands in this url 
https://saucelabs.com/resources/articles/the-selenium-2018click2019-command, nothing has worked.

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from unittest import TestCase

#driver = webdriver.Chrome('/path/to/chromedriver')  # Optional argument, if not specified will search path.
class GoToLogin(TestCase):

    driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    driver.get('http://192.168.56.101:8000/login/');
    #time.sleep(5) # Let the user actually see something!
    user_field = driver.find_element_by_id('id_username')
    user_field.send_keys('lruedc')

    password_field = driver.find_element_by_id('id_password')
    password_field.send_keys('lejoruca123')

    button_field = driver.find_element_by_id('btnlogin')
    button_field.click()

    #time.sleep(5) # Let the user actually see something!
    user_field.submit()
    self.driver.quit()
```

the html file content:

```
<div id="menuform">
    <div style="width: 270px;">
         <ul class="menu_ulli">
           <li class="menu_ulli"  name="Procesos">
             <a data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Procesos</a>
             <ul class="menu_ulli">
               <li class="menu_ulli" id="Prestar Servicios" name="Prestar Servicios"><a href="{% url 'key_process_indicator_bsc:process_indicator' %}">Prestar Servicios</a>
                   <ul class="menu_ulli">
                       <li class="menu_ulli" name="Gestionar Servicios BPO">
                           <a href="{% url 'key_process_indicator_bsc:process_indicator' %}">Gestionar Servicios BPO</a>
                           <ul class="menu_ulli">
                               <li class="menu_ulli" name="Generar la Estrategía del Servicio"><a href="{% url 'key_process_indicator_bsc:process_indicator' %}">Generar la Estrategía del Servicio</a>
                                   <ul class="menu_ulli">
                                        <li class="menu_ulli" name="Gestiornar vertical-Servicio al cliente"><a href="{% url 'key_process_indicator_bsc:process_indicator' %}">Gestiornar vertical-Servicio al cliente</a>
                                         <ul class="menu_ulli">
                                            <li class="menu_ulli" name="Analizar línea de Servicio"><a href="{% url 'key_process_indicator_bsc:process_indicator' %}">Analizar línea de Servicio</a></li>
                                            <li class="menu_ulli" name="Diseñar la estrategia"><a href="{% url 'key_process_indicator_bsc:process_indicator' %}">Diseñar la estrategia</a></li>
                                            <li class="menu_ulli" name="Comunicar la estrategia"><a href="{% url 'key_process_indicator_bsc:process_indicator' %}">Comunicar la estrategia</a></li>
                                         </ul>
                                        </li>
                                        <li class="menu_ulli" name="Gestiornar vertical-Ventas Telefónicas"><a href="{% url 'key_process_indicator_bsc:process_indicator' %}">Gestiornar vertical-Ventas Telefónicas</a></li>
                                        <li class="menu_ulli" name="Gestiornar vertical-Cobranzas"><a href="{% url 'key_process_indicator_bsc:process_indicator' %}">Gestiornar vertical-Cobranzas</a></li>
                                        <li class="menu_ulli" name="Gestiornar vertical-Back Office"><a href="{% url 'key_process_indicator_bsc:process_indicator' %}">Gestiornar vertical-Back Office</a></li>
                                   </ul>
                               </li>
                               <li class="menu_ulli" name="Gestionar Acuerdos y Cambios en la Operación"><a href="{% url 'key_process_indicator_bsc:process_indicator' %}">Gestionar Acuerdos y Cambios en la Operación</a></li>
                               <li class="menu_ulli" name="Pronosticar, planificar y programar recursos"><a href="{% url 'key_process_indicator_bsc:process_indicator' %}">Pronosticar, planificar y programar recursos</a></li>
                           </ul>
                       </li>
                   </ul>
               </li>                
             </ul>
           </li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="menu_ulli">
           <li class="menu_ulli" name="Estrategia">
             <a data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Estrategia</a>
             <ul class="menu_ulli">
               <li class="menu_ulli" name="Corporativo"><a href="{% url 'key_process_indicator_bsc:bsc_indicator' %}">Corporativo</a>
                   <ul class="menu_ulli">
                       <li class="menu_ulli" name="Corporativo Emtelco"><a href="{% url 'key_process_indicator_bsc:bsc_indicator' %}">Corporativo Emtelco</a>
                       <ul class="menu_ulli">
                           <li class="menu_ulli" id="1" name="BSC 2013-2014"><a href="{% url 'key_process_indicator_bsc:bsc_indicator' %}">BSC 2013-2014</a></li>
                           <li class="menu_ulli" id="2" name="BSC 2014-2015"><a href="{% url 'key_process_indicator_bsc:bsc_indicator' %}">BSC 2014-2015</a></li>
                       </ul>
                       </li>
                   </ul>
               </li>
               <li class="menu_ulli" name="UEN"><a href="{% url 'key_process_indicator_bsc:process_indicator' %}">UEN</a>
                   <ul class="menu_ulli">
                       <li class="menu_ulli" name="Contact Center"><a href="{% url 'key_process_indicator_bsc:bsc_indicator' %}">Contact Center</a>
                           <ul class="menu_ulli">
                               <li class="menu_ulli" id="3" name="BSC 2013-2014"><a href="{% url 'key_process_indicator_bsc:bsc_indicator' %}">BSC 2013-2014</a></li>
                               <li class="menu_ulli" id="4" name="BSC 2014-2015"><a href="{% url 'key_process_indicator_bsc:bsc_indicator' %}">BSC 2014-2015</a></li>
                           </ul>
                       </li>
                       <li class="menu_ulli" name="Premisas"><a href="{% url 'key_process_indicator_bsc:bsc_indicator' %}">Premisas</a>
                           <ul class="menu_ulli">
                               <li class="menu_ulli" id="5" name="BSC 2013-2014"><a href="{% url 'key_process_indicator_bsc:bsc_indicator' %}">BSC 2013-2014</a></li>
                               <li class="menu_ulli" id="6" name="BSC 2014-2015"><a href="{% url 'key_process_indicator_bsc:bsc_indicator' %}">BSC 2014-2015</a></li>
                           </ul>
                       </li>
                       <li class="menu_ulli" name="Servicios Complementarios"><a href="{% url 'key_process_indicator_bsc:bsc_indicator' %}">Servicios Complementarios</a>
                           <ul class="menu_ulli">
                               <li class="menu_ulli" id="7" name="BSC 2013-2014"><a href="{% url 'key_process_indicator_bsc:bsc_indicator' %}">BSC 2013-2014</a></li>
                               <li class="menu_ulli" id="8" name="BSC 2014-2015"><a href="{% url 'key_process_indicator_bsc:bsc_indicator' %}">BSC 2014-2015</a></li>
                           </ul>
                       </li>
                   </ul>
               </li>                  
             </ul>
           </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

I need to make click on whatever `<a>` tag.

Comment: Can you share the html?

Comment: of course, this is the html file

Comment: If you tried to add file it didn't work. It will be better if you add it to the question.

Comment: guy i don't know, i have the html file, but i don't know how put it here.

Comment: Click on "edit" under your question and add the html there as text

Comment: There is no element with ID `btnlogin` in your code...Also (and not related), those `menu_ulli` classes are extremely redundant.

Comment: well, i begin with the login , is a button on the login html, the test login me, now, on someone <a> tag to make click, this is a menu in the left part of screen. and for the class i undertand, i am begin with this around the python world and the programming in general.

Comment: this is other template but i want to make click on someone <a> tag, simple, but i don't know.

Comment: I'm not asking for opinions as is structurally the code, else how to make a line of code on the functional test to be Click on <a> tag, whatever <a> tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To click on any `<a>` tag as you mention in the comments you can do

```
driver.find_element_by_tag_name("a").click()
```

This will click on the first `<a>` in the html (if its clickable).

However, clicking on element found by tag name is not recommended as there are usually many tags of the same type. Its better to use [other methods](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/locating-elements.html#locating-elements) to locate elements.